# A few problems operator overloading in python / pygame in a custom array class

Tags: python, operator-overloading, pygame, typeerror

Hello and thank you for checking out this question. I, for a basic tile based game I am making, made my own container class that holds a matrix of items / values that represent a map in the world. To do this I learned how about operator overloading. For the most part, everything seems okay, but I am getting some results that are confusing to me.

```
class mapArray(object):

    def __init__(self, mapdata = None, (width,height) = None, fillnumber = 0):
        #If you are already given a map array, then you can just provide
        # that first, otherwise leave it as none. Fill number is used to change the entire 
        # map array so that the map will be a different tile type. 0 is most likely just grass.
        print "horses"
        if (mapdata == None) and (width, height) == None:
            self.mapdata = []

        elif mapdata is not None:
            self.mapdata = mapdata

        elif (width,height) is not None:
            self.mapdata = [[fillnumber] * width] * height

    def __setitem__(self, (x,y), value):
        #Allows you to assign values more intuitively with the array
        self.mapdata[y][x] = value

    def __getitem__(self, (x,y)):
        #Just reverses it so it works intuitively and the array is 
        # indexed simply like map[x,y] instead of map[y][x]
        return mapArray(self.mapdata[y][x])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mapdata)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.mapdata)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mapdata)
```

The **getitem** works fine. I have the constructor set to either take in a given list of lists, or provide a length and width that just makes an array of that size. Here are the results I get when I provide a size for the array, as opposed to giving it my own values.

```
testlist1 = mapArray(None, (3,3), 4)
print testlist1
testlist1[0,1] = 5
print testlist1
```

This gives me these results:

```
[[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4]]
[[5,4,4],[5,4,4],[5,4,4]]
```

The first result makes sense, but the second result seems to show a problem in my **setitem** method that I overrode. Why does it replace the first index of every list?

And also confusing to me is what happens when I provide my own list of lists to replace the mapdata argument.

```
randommap = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
testlist2 = mapArray(randommap)
print testlist2
```

That code gives me this TypeError:

```
def __init__(self, mapdata = None, (width,height) = None, fillnumber = 0):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

to me this seems like it is saying that the mapdata is not iterable when it is set to None, but shouldnt the randommap lists I provide replace the mapdata? Perhaps there is a problem with the conditional statements I have setup so that it never gets replaced. I can't seem to narrow down what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am new to operator overloading so if there are any more efficient ways to do this let me know. I know that numpy exists to do most of this for me but I wanted to do this on my own.
Thanks again!
Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `__init__()`. Specifically this line:

```
self.mapdata = [[fillnumber] * width] * height
```

This creates `height` references to the same list. The fix is:

```
self.mapdata = [[fillnumber] * width for x in xrange(height)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though I understand now that it references to the same list but I don't know if I completely understand why this happens. Why isn't it simply just creating its own list?

Comment: Because list multiplication doesn't copy the objects within the list. The objects may not even be copyable in the first place.

Comment: Oh I see, I think I understand, thank you!  Would you also happen to have any input on the second issue I mentioned, which is giving me an error that I can't seem to find the origin of?

Comment: Oh, well, that one's easier. How you've specified it asks for a 2-tuple. `None` is not a 2-tuple. So either give it a 2-tuple (`(None, None)` perhaps), or split it into two arguments.

Comment: Oh, it did some strange to me how I had `(width,height) = None` now that I think about it. Thank you very much for your answers!